# C# ASP.NET MVC Manually Accessing Request.Form & Potentially Dangerous values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm serializing and saving form and query string data to a database for each user request.  This particular submitted model already has the [AllowHtml] attribute and submits fine to the controller.  The issue is inside the Global.asax file where I log the request, when I access this form value I get the exception:

> "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client (...)."

```
protected void Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var formData = (Request.Form.Count == 0) ? "" : serializer.Serialize(Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(x => x != null).ToDictionary(k => k, k => Request.Form[k]));
    ...
}
```

Error gets thrown when it tries to access Request.Form[k] when it contains invalid characters.

Comment: Not tested, but you might be able to use `Request.Unvalidated.Form[k]`

Comment: Try adding `[ValidateInput(false)] ` to the method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke please post that as a answer.  It is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing values with `Request.Form[]` will trigger request validation (hence the exception). You can use the `Unvalidated` property of `HttpRequest` to get the request values without triggering validation.

Replace

```
Request.Form[k]
```

with

```
Request.Unvalidated.Form[k]
```

Use with caution - from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.unvalidated(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Security Note: If you use this property, you must manually check the data for potential cross-site scripting attacks.

Comment: Is there any risk of cross-site scripting if I am serializing the values and storing them in a database, being sent as a stored procedure nvarchar(max) param?

Comment: No (not AFAIK), I added that more for the benefit of others who might read this (in your case your just logging the data)